# how to create code for ignore double data in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

this is my controller:

```
    public function tambah_ijin()
{
    $data=array(
    'username' =>$_POST['username'],
    'tgl_ijin'=>$_POST['tgl_ijin'],
    'ket'=>$_POST['ket']
    );
    $result=$this->m_member->insert_ijin($data);
    //echo json_encode($res);
    if($result){
        redirect('member');
    }else{
        echo "Penambahan Data Gagal <br>";
        echo '<a href="'.site_url('member').'">Kembali</a>';
    }
}
```

this is my model:

```
class M_member extends CI_Model {

    public function insert_ijin($data)
    {
        $query=$this->db->insert('absensi',$data);
        return $query;
    }


}
```

this is my table result:
[member table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYukc.png)

I want one user can not be an entry at the same time

one user can only post once a day

Comment: This question gives us very low informations, it will be hard to answer it without further information. have you tried something ? What are you trying to express ?

Comment: Set one or more of the fields to be unique. If you only want unique usernames, then set that to be unique. If you want one username per day, set a unique flag for those combined fields. You can also do a `select ... where` before an insert.

Comment: iam so sorry,, iam newbie in programming,I hope someone can help this

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if the post already exists.

```
class M_member extends CI_Model {
     public function insert_ijin($data,$user)
        {

    if($this->exists($user) != true){
           $this->db->insert('absensi',$data);
            return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0? true:false; //returns true/false
        }
    }



    function exists($user){

    $query = $this->db->query("select from where YOUR QUERY $user, date()...");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {return true;}
    else{return false;}

    } 
}
```